# 2D LWJGL with OpenGL - Enabling depth testing for layering 2D textures?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, depth-testing

What would I need to add to my OpenGL init method to enable depth testing, and how would I actually use it for texture layering?

I would have to extend the last parameter of glOrtho to something more extreme than -1, and of course glEnable depth testing. Then to use it, I can only assume that I change the third parameter of glVertex to something that isn't 0 to send it in front / behind of other textures.

I try this, and the damn textures don't even show. xD I must be missing something.

---

EDIT: RE: Tim's response

whenever i made the image's z more extreme than -1 it didnt show the screen was just black.

```
void initGL(){

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST); //depth test enabled

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 1, -10);//far changed to -10
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

and

```
void loadBG(int theLoadedOne){

GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, theLoadedOne);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
GL11.glVertex3f(-width/2,height/2, -2);//new z value

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
GL11.glVertex3f(width/2,height/2,-2);//new z value

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
GL11.glVertex3f(width/2,-height/2,-2);//new z value

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
GL11.glVertex3f(-width/2,-height/2,-2);//new z value

GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glFlush();

}
```

and

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

...

            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){  //dont mind this for loop
                bg.loadThisBG(0);  //its here for reasons
            }
            updateFPS();

        Display.update();

    } Display.destroy();

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does texture layering affect depth testing? Why do you have to extend the projected volume? Ah, you use multiple quads shifted in `z` direction, combined with blending? So you're not using shaders? Please elaborate/rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes what you said. Using z to layer them in the view so that some will be more behind others.

Comment: Can you show the code to do this? With this kind of multitexturing, you need to order the quads from back to front to make the blending work. You use screen-aligned quads?

Comment: i dont know about why I need any blending. i'm not sure what screen-aligned means; each quad has its own coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you switched near and far plane. Have a look at [gluOrtho2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml). It just calls `glOrtho` with `near=-1` and `far=+1`, resulting in the z coordinates switching sign (`m33=-2/(far-near)`). However, with the values given above, `m33=-2/(-10-1)` is positive, and the z axis reversed to standard workflow.

This consequences in the quad being viewed from the back.

OpenGL matrix manipulation methods do no care what you feed them; except when values would led to a division by zero.

---

Assuming there is no modelview transform, and only the one matrix contributing to the projection one, here is what I think is happening:

The z value transform from world to NDC space is `z_ndc = -9/11 * z_w + 2/11` (set near and far into the orthographic matrix and take the third row). Now, `z_w=-2`, and so `z_ndc = 20/11`. This is out of the NDC space boundaries and thrown away.

Well, I assume that this test is implicitly enabled/disabled with the Z test itself. Next suspect would be backface culling...

Comment: are you insisting i should use gluOrtho2D instead and then try it with adding depth tests?

Comment: No, I just pointed you to `gluOrtho2D` to show how it calls `glOrtho`. Change the last two parameters to something like `near=-10` and `far=+10`. After reenabling the depth test, the quad should now be visible.

Comment: thanks man, it worked. the problem i'm having now is, when i put a texture w/ transparency over another texture, the second texture isn't showing under where the transparency should be. http://i.imgur.com/sTNU8.png?1 Here is a quick demonstration I did with transparent text over a blue textured square. The text's z is 0 and the square's z is -9. How do I make it so that textures show behind other textures' transparency?

Comment: You need to setup _blending_. Look for `glBlendFunc`; [here's](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) a nice playground.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your context includes a depth buffer (not sure about lwjgl buffer creation...)

All you need should be:

- Call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` during initialization
- Add depth buffer bit to glClear `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`
- Define z coordinate to be between near and far values of orthographic matrix.

Comment: i tried what you said and the background was just black. more details in the original post.

Comment: @GlassZee: does this code actually work if you don't use depth testing? For one thing you need to call glLoadIdentity every time before you call glOrtho (it multiplies orthographic matrix with what's currently on the stack). Also I'm not 100% positive but I believe that the value for near must be less than the value of far (currently you have near > far), which might be screwing things up.

Comment: @Tim oh well, just writing up a nice answer for this, _then_ reading your comment...

Comment: yes it does work without the depth testing, but apparently the textures are being viewed from the back. I'll try to fix everything up and then try what you said again. I'm actually getting on a plane today so I won't be able to do it until later.